# If $a \neq b$ be 2 reals, and $\alpha$ be irrational number, prove that there exists a rational number $r$ such that $r \alpha$ lies between a and b.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

If a and b are two distinct real numbers and $\alpha$ is an irrational number, prove that there exists a rational number $r$ such that $r \alpha$ lies between a and b.

I think the proof will be the similar to the irrational part of this proof:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

But actually I do not understand why $\rho = \frac{p \sqrt{2}}{q} \in (a,b)$, could anyone explain this for me?

Also how can I use this proof in proving my question?

**My attempt is: I am editing it**

Comment: Was someone chasing you when you posted this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the proof of your first question is much simpler.

Let $a < b$ be two real numbers, and $\alpha$ an irrational number.

**Case 1 :** $\alpha > 0$. Then you have
$$\frac{a}{\alpha} < \frac{b}{\alpha}$$
so using the archimedian property of $\mathbb{R}$, you can get a rational number $r$ such that 
$$\frac{a}{\alpha} < r < \frac{b}{\alpha}$$
i.e.
$$a < r\alpha < b$$

**Case 2 :** $\alpha < 0$. Then you have
$$\frac{a}{\alpha} > \frac{b}{\alpha}$$
so using the archimedian property of $\mathbb{R}$, you can get a rational number $r$ such that 
$$\frac{a}{\alpha} > r > \frac{b}{\alpha}$$
i.e.
$$a < r\alpha < b$$

Comment: I think the second inequality from the density of rationals in reals and not from Archemidean property.

Comment: Yes, but you can prove the density of rationals in reals using archimedian property. This is done is the second paragraph of the proof of your post !

Comment: what if a<b<0 ?

Comment: Well, if $a<b<0$, then $0 < -b < -a$, so by the previous case, there exists a rational $r$ such that $-b < r < -a$, and you get $a < -r < b$. So there exists still a rational between $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

For your problem regarding $\rho$, just break the inequality

$$p\frac{\sqrt{2}}{b}<q<p\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a},$$

into two parts and manipulate them. The left hand side inequality $p\frac{\sqrt{2}}{b}<q$ is equivalent to $p\frac{\sqrt{2}}{q}<b$  (multiply by $b$ and divide by $q$). Doing a similar thing to the right hand inequality will show that $\rho\in(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple proof, based on the archimedean property of $\mathbf R$:

We may suppose $\alpha >0$ and $a<b$, and take $n$ such that $\;\dfrac{\alpha} n <b-a $. Let     $m$ the smallest integer such that $a<m\,\dfrac{\alpha} n$. From our choice for $n$, we have
$$(m-1)\frac\alpha n<a<m\,\dfrac{\alpha} n <b,$$
so we can take $\;r=\dfrac mn$.